# Angular 2 gulp task for convert multiple scss to single css

Tags: angular, sass, gulp

```
app
-file1
 -- file1.ts
 -- file1.html
 -- file1.scss

 -file2
 -- file2.ts
 -- file2.html
 -- file2.scss

 -file3
 -- file3.ts
 -- file3.html
 -- file3.scss
```

My project structure like this.
I am trying to convert all my scss files into single css. looking for Angular 2 gulp task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import your all files in one single file like this

```
-style.scss
@import "includes/file2";
@import "includes/file3";
```

then run convert command of gulp

Answer (score 1):

> Try the code below. What I basically do is import all scss files to
>   single file (styles.scss) then convert it. Then watch for any changes in scss files to update css

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```